# Use Get-Content and split json file into 3 parts

Tags: arrays, json, powershell-2.0

If I have a json file in the following format:

```
{
    "server" : {
        "name" : "myUbuntuServer1",
        "imageRef" : "3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001",
        "flavorRef" : "9" }
}
{
    "server" : {
        "name" : "myUbuntuServer2",
        "imageRef" : "3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001",
        "flavorRef" : "6" }
}
{
    "server" : {
        "name" : "myUbuntuServer3",
        "imageRef" : "3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001",
        "flavorRef" : "3" }
}
```

How would I split it up according to the number of servers detected in the file and assign each block as an array item, i.e.

Array item 0

```
{
    "server" : {
        "name" : "myUbuntuServer1",
        "imageRef" : "3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001",
        "flavorRef" : "9" }
}
```

Array item 1

```
{
    "server" : {
        "name" : "myUbuntuServer2",
        "imageRef" : "3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001",
        "flavorRef" : "6" }
}
```

Array item 2

```
{
    "server" : {
        "name" : "myUbuntuServer3",
        "imageRef" : "3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001",
        "flavorRef" : "3" }
}
```

This is my code so far:

```
$file = "servers.json"
$request = Get-Content $file
createServer $request
```

I want to split the file into segments according to the server and then wrap the `$request` assignment and `createServer` function in a for loop and pass each item in the array through.

So it would look something like:

```
$file = "servers.json"
$request = Get-Content $file

#split file up into three here and assign to an array

foreach ($request in $array) {
    createServer $request
}
```

How would I accomplish this in Powershell v2?

Comment: The JSON source is not valid format.

Comment: @GiovanniDiGregorio - how should it look like? I think I may have set it up incorrectly

Comment: @GiovanniDiGregorio - I've spotted it! Thank you

Comment: JSON is still not valid, this is a valid format: [
    {
        "server": {
            "name": "myUbuntuServer1",
            "imageRef": "3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001",
            "flavorRef": "6"
        }
    },
    {
        "server": {
            "name": "myUbuntuServer2",
            "imageRef": "3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001",
            "flavorRef": "6"
        }
    },
    {
        "server": {
            "name": "myUbuntuServer3",
            "imageRef": "3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001",
            "flavorRef": "6"
        }
    }
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON format is wrong, this is a valid format:

```
{
    "servers": [
        {
            "name": "myUbuntuServer1",
            "imageRef": "3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001",
            "flavorRef": "9"
        },
        {
            "name": "myUbuntuServer1",
            "imageRef": "3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001",
            "flavorRef": "9"
        },
        {
            "name": "myUbuntuServer1",
            "imageRef": "3afe97b2-26dc-49c5-a2cc-a2fc8d80c001",
            "flavorRef": "9"
        }
    ]
}
```

Where you can iterate inside the *servers* key value which it is already an array.
Hope you help.